# makeCluster cannot open the connection -- error handling strategies?

Tags: r, parallel-processing

An automated system is used to launch an R script that uses makeCluster to open a cluster of 35 nodes on a machine with 36 CPUs. (AWS c4.8xlarge running up to date Ubuntu and R)

```
n.nodes = 35
cl <- makeCluster(n.nodes,
                  outfile = "debug.txt")
```

The following error as written to debug.txt appears on a somewhat regular basis

```
    starting worker pid=2017 on localhost:11823 at 21:15:57.390
    Error in socketConnection(master, port = port, blocking = TRUE, open = "a+b",  :
    cannot open the connection
    Calls: <Anonymous> ... doTryCatch -> recvData -> makeSOCKmaster -> socketConnection
    In addition: Warning message:
    In socketConnection(master, port = port, blocking = TRUE, open = "a+b",  :
    localhost:11823 cannot be opened
    Execution halted
```

The pid and port number are session specific. The program fails to proceed when this error is encountered.

**Question 1:** Are there error handling methods that will recognize this has happened and try to make the cluster again?

Note: The following does not work

```
attempt=0
while(dim(showConnections())[1] < n.nodes && attempt<=25){ # 25 chancees to create n.nodes connections
print(attempt)
closeAllConnections() # Close any open connections
portnum = round(runif(1,11000,11998)) # Randomly Choose a Port
tryCatch({ # Try to create the cluster
    evalWithTimeout({
        cl <- makeCluster(n.nodes,
                    outfile = "debug.txt",
                    port=portnum)
        },timeout = 120) # Give it two minutes and then stop trying
      },TimeoutException = function(x) {print(paste("Failed to Create Cluster",portnum))}) # If it fails, print the portnum it tried
      attempt=attempt+1 # Update attempt
      Sys.sleep(2) # Take a breather
    }
```

**Question 2:** If there is not a way to automatically retry making the cluster, is there a way to check if the port can be opened before attempting to run makeCluster?

Note: This system must be fully automated/self contained. It must recognize an error, handle/fix the problem, and then proceed without manual intervention.

Answer (score 2):

`parallel::makeCluster()`, or `parallel::makePSOCKcluster()` used internally here, does not provide any automatic retrial.  If you look at the code of `parallel::makePSOCKcluster()` you implement your own version based on `parallel:::newPSOCKnode()` that sets up each individual worker.  That's a internal function, so it should be considered a "hack".

In the [future](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/future) package (I'm the author), there is `future::makeClusterPSOCK()` with companion `future::makeNodePSOCK()` - both are part of the public API.   That provides you with building blocks to run your own improved version.   Also, you can write your own function `myCreateNode()` to setup a cluster node that retries and pass use it as `cl <- future::makeClusterPSOCK(..., makeNode = myCreateNode)`.  Sorry, that's all I have time for right now.